# Why image src is not updating even using property binding [src]?

Tags: angular, async-await, html5-canvas

I'm trying to capture screen using `getDisplayMedia()` (I have used external js to use `getDisplayMedia()` as it is not supported by angular 4 i guess). On first click event, it is showing accurate screenshot image, but after that it doesn't update image from 2nd click event onward.

I had tried:

- To create dynamic element with update `src`, but `bypassSecurityTrustUrl()` needs `src` to be bounded as property. ie `[src]`="screenshot". So I guess i can't do this in dynamic element creation.
- To clear canvas and image `src` initially whenever click event occurs.
  Also please note resource link is `base64` based URL.

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs/Subscription';
import { TranslateService } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { DomSanitizer, SafeResourceUrl, SafeUrl } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NotificationService } from './primary/services/notification.service';
import { AppConstants } from './shared/AppConstants';
import { CookieService } from './primary/services/cookie-service';
import {DialogboxService} from './primary/services/dialogbox.service';

//Core javascript classes.
declare var MediaRecorder: any;
declare var getStream: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  // _navigator:any = null;
  displayPopup: boolean = false;
  msgs: any;
  subscription: Subscription;
  flag: any;
  stream = null;
  shadowRoot = null;
  videoplayer = null;
  chunks = [];
  mediaRecorder = null;
  status = 'Inactive';
  recording = null;
  screenshot = null;
  validNavigation = 0;
  contx = null;
  canvas = null;

  constructor(public notifyer: NotificationService, private translate: TranslateService,
              public _cookieService:CookieService, private dialogboxService:DialogboxService,
              private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) {

    AppConstants.LANGUAGE = 'en';
    translate.setDefaultLang(AppConstants.LANGUAGE);
    translate.use(AppConstants.LANGUAGE);
    this.subscription = this.notifyer.notificationChange
      .subscribe(msgs => {
        this.msgs = msgs;
      });
  }

  ngOnInit(){
    this.videoplayer = document.getElementById("invisibleVideo")
    this.canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth; //document.width is obsolete
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  }

  //to take timeout
  sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
  }

  async _takeScreenshot(){
    this.stream = await getStream();
    this.mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder(this.stream, {mimeType: 'video/webm'});
    this.mediaRecorder.addEventListener('dataavailable', event => {
      if (event.data && event.data.size > 0) {
        this.chunks.push(event.data);
      }
    });
    this.mediaRecorder.start(100);
    await this.sleep(1200);
    this.mediaRecorder.stop();
    this.mediaRecorder = null;
    this.stream.getTracks().forEach(track => track.stop());
    this.stream = null;
    //allow dynamic source base64 URL
    this.recording = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(window.URL.createObjectURL(new Blob(this.chunks, {type: 'video/webm'})));
    await this.sleep(600);
    this.contx = this.canvas.getContext("2d")
    this.contx.drawImage(this.videoplayer,0,0)
    //allow dynamic source base64 URL
    this.screenshot = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustUrl(this.canvas.toDataURL('image/png'))
    this.canvas.width = window.innerWidth; //document.width is obsolete
    this.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
    this.displayPopup = true;
  }

  takeSelfie(){
    this._takeScreenshot();
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<script src="../assets/adapter.js"></script>
<style>
  video {
    --video-width: 100%;
    width: var(--video-width);
    height: calc(var(--video-width) * (16 / 9));
  }
</style>
<p-dialog [positionTop]="40" (onHide)="displayPopup=false" [styleClass]="'popup_width'"
  header='Report Bug' [(visible)]="displayPopup" modal="modal" [responsive]="true">
  <div id="ssDiv">
    <img [src]="screenshot" id="ssImg" class="ssImg">
  </div>
  <div id="container">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
    <div id="vDiv">
      <video style="display:none" controls="true" id="invisibleVideo" playsinline
              autoplay loop muted [src]="recording ? recording : ''"></video>
    </div>
  </div>
  </p-dialog>
<button class="report-bug-button" (click)="takeSelfie()">
  <i class="fa fa-camera" aria-hidden="true" style="color:white;font-size: 25px;"></i>
</button>
```

**adapter.js**

```
var getStream = function getStream(){
  if (navigator.getDisplayMedia) {
    return navigator.getDisplayMedia({video: true});
  } else if (navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia) {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({video: true});
  } else {
    return navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: {mediaSource: 'screen'}});
  }
}
```

I expect every time click event occurs, image should update with new screenshot, rather staying on older one.

Comment: Can you try by setting value to `null` and then assign new value to `screenshot` in `_takeScreenshot` method.

Comment: Yes! I did try this one also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newly recorded screen data chunks are getting appended in array. `this.chunks.push(event.data);`

Whenever video player starts playing recording, it always starts with what recorded at starting. So, screenshot is always taken from initial frames. This was actual bug.
Solution is clearing chunk array inside `_takeScreenshot`.

`this.chunks = []`